# AsyncIO for loop conversion

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, python-asyncio

I am new with AsyncIO. I want some help converting the below scenario.

I have a set of json files, these will be read and pass it to the post request. This operation does sequentially N number of times

I want to covert the below to use parallelism using AsyncIO to do the operation asynchronously.

```
def test(n):
  num = 0
  for names in os.list(dir):
     filename = os.path.join(.,b=name)
     while num> n:
      request.post(url, filename)
      num = +1
```

This code runs for all json files sequentially. Can some one help me write the code in
asynchronous way that one thread will be running one with 1st json file and if there is any ideal cpu it should run with 2nd json and go on

I am new to this. Can anyone help me with this code approach. Thank you

Comment: your `while` loop will never run for positive `n`. And it seems that it's not needed there